# Why the scaladoc in zeal showed in messy code?

Tags: scala, zeal

I downloaded the scala document in Zeal, then I open the `List`.

[image]

Its contents is messy code. However, when I click the `Open URL`, the content in Chrome is normal.

[image]

So I would like to know how to address it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please use project's [GitHub issues](https://github.com/zealdocs/zeal/issues) to report bugs. Stack Overflow isn't really a bug tracker.